# sqlalchemy create_engine issue with oracle

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

I am trying to connect to my Oracle DB and I can not create the engine:

```
engine = create_engine('oracle://user:pass@localhost:1521/dbname')
```

the error I get is:

```
/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/oracle/cx_oracle.pyc in __init__(self, auto_setinputsizes, exclude_setinputsizes, auto_convert_lobs, threaded, allow_twophase, coerce_to_decimal, coerce_to_unicode, arraysize, **kwargs)
705         if hasattr(self.dbapi, 'version'):
706             self.cx_oracle_ver = tuple([int(x) for x in
707                                         self.dbapi.version.split('.')])
708         else:
709             self.cx_oracle_ver = (0, 0, 0)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0b1'
```

My OS: RedHat 7

Oracle Express 11g

Python 2.7 Anaconda

cx_Oracle 6.0

cx_Oracle.clientversion() = (12, 2, 0, 1, 0)

Any Idea how this could be fixed?

Comment: This looks like bug. What version is SQLAlchemy? (`import sqlalchemy; print(sqlalchemy.__version__)`) If it's old, is there a chance to upgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug (or at least an incompatibility) in SQLAlchemy due to the 'b' in cx_Oracle's pre-release version 6.0b1.  The issue has been reported [here](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/3975/) with a suggested fix that you could apply to your own install of SQLAlchemy, or you can wait for a fix to be released.  Alternatively, that issue will not be present if you use cx_Oracle version 5.3.